# jQuery- Can't Add div with certain class name

Tags: jquery

I have been pulling my hair out try to figure out why this doesn't work.

So basically, I have multiple instances of the same mockup on the page. But I only want to insert an empty `div` with a class in between these instances. I have tried `append`, `appendTo`, `prepend`, `prependTo`, `before`, `after`,... Basically, a lot of them, but none of them work as expect, and I have no idea why. So here is the example code

```
<div class="wrapper class1">
  <div class="element_body">
  Stuff here 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper class2">
  <div class="element_body">
  Stuff here 
  </div>
</div>
.....
```

And I try to insert `<div class="div-for-labels"></div>` in between `wrapper` and `element_body`.

BUT 
It only works right for the first instance. Any other instances right after that do not work. It either removed the `class1`, only keep `wrapper` class, and doesn't insert `<div class="div-for-labels"></div>` at all.

BUT 
if I change `<div class="div-for-labels"></div>` to `<div class=".div-for-labels"></div>`

Then everything WORKS!

This ,TOTALLY, does not make any sense to me.

why one works, but the other doesn't work?
why it removes the class from the parent div? 
why it works right for the first instances, but fail for all of the other ones?

I tried many different ways 
`_this` is the specific instances that I'm targeting, I don't insert it all at the same time. I insert it one by one.

`$(_this).prepend('<div class="div-for-labels"></div>');`

Same thing for `append`, `after`, etc.

Or
    var $labelDiv = $('');
    `$(_this).prepend($labelDiv);

None of them works. Please help! :(

------EDIT

ok guys, thank you so much for you guys' help. It is something very straight that it will not work with the way I named other divs on the same page (I think). I was able to solved the problem just by renaming the class that I use for the new `div`

```
<div class="my-panel my-tabs" data-id="firstID">

      <div class="my-panel-body">

        <div class="my-panel--single" data-index="0">

            <div class="my-panel__label active">

                <span>Test 1</span>

            </div>

            <div class="my-panel__content active" data-index="0">
                 Here is the content
            </div>

       </div>

       <div class="my-panel--single" data-index="1">

            <div class="my-panel__label">

                <span>Test 1</span>

            </div>

            <div class="my-panel__content" data-index="1">
                 Here is the content
            </div>

       </div>

       //Many other block of `my-panel--single`

     </div>

 </div>
```

So here is the steps of my problem

- I have many instances of `my-panel` on the page (each has a unique data id), and for each of the instance, I want to append `<div class="my-panel-labels"></div>` in between of `my-panel` and `my-panel-body`.
- But for some odd reasons, when I tried to do so, the `my-tabs` class with `my-panel` div will be removed, and the new div is also NOT appended.
- But if I change the class name to any other name, it will work (explained why when I add (`.`) to the class name then it works.

I was able to solve it by changing the class name, but still have no idea why that specific name doesn't work. So if any of you know the reason why, it would be a hug enlightenment for my little jQuery knowledge.

Again, thank you so much for you guys' help.

Comment: it works fine? https://jsfiddle.net/8obrq6xs/

Comment: Your code seems to be working perfectly fine, as you have described. Unless, we aren't able to understand your problem, kindly rephrase it.

Comment: I solved by renaming the class name. I explained it in my original question. It would be great if you guys know the reason behind what happened. Thanks!

Comment: Too many hyphens, can be misinterpreted as an operator like subtraction `-` or decrement `--` so something like `my-panel-labels` could look like an expression. Especially if you have variables like `panel` or  an object like `labels` That would explain why you get missing elements. Your strings are parsed as expressions which then everything is parsed willy nilly. That would explain why a dot was accepted as well. The dot probably changed your statement back to DOM because .label looks like a property.

Comment: That might be the reason. But I'm pretty sure, I don't name my variables as `panels` or `labels`, but should be watch out for now. Need to be careful when using BEM too then. http://getbem.com/naming/

Comment: BEM is great if you're the only developer or your team is spot on. In your IDE (text editor) Take a look at that trouble class and compare the color of the text to that of a known working class. The syntax highlighting pattern should be different.

Comment: it actually has the exact same color as the working class. I probably should move on, and think about it later since I have spent a good amount of time trying to chase this issue. Thank you so much your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you want to do? I have included each method you have mentioned in this demo.

### Demo

```js
$('.DL').append(`<div class="DIV1">[DIV1]Method: .append()][Loc: after DD7</div>`);

$(`<div class="DIV2">[DIV2]Method: .appendTo()][Loc: after DIV1</div>`).appendTo('.DL');

$('.DL').prepend(`<div class="DIV3">[DIV3]Method: .prepend()][Loc: before DTA</div>`);

$(`<div class="DIV4">[DIV4]Method: .prependTo()][Loc: before DIV3</div>`).prependTo('.DL');

$('.DL').after(`<div class="DIV5">[DIV5]Method: .after()][Loc: behind DL</div>`);

$('.DL').before(`<div class="DIV6">[DIV6]Method: .before()][Loc: in front of DL</div>`);
```

```css
.DL {
  border: 2px dashed lime;
}

div:nth-of-type(odd) {
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red
}

div:nth-of-type(even) {
  color: blue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h3>DL</h3>
<dl class='DL'>
  <dt class='DTA'>DTA</dt>
  <dd class='DD1'>DD1</dd>
  <dd class='DD2'>DD2</dd>
  <dd class='DD3'>DD3</dd>
  <dd class='DD4'>DD4</dd>

  <dt class='DTB'>DTB</dt>
  <dd class='DD5'>DD5</dd>
  <dd class='DD6'>DD6</dd>
  <dd class='DD7'>DD7</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: I know what `append`, `appendTo`, etc. do, they just not doing the right thing for me. For some reasons, when I try to append a new empty div with a class in between my existing divs, it wiped out existing classes of the outer most div. And another weird thing is that when I change the class name for the new div from `newDivClass` to `.newDivClass`, then everything works as expect.

Comment: A class name is prefixed with a  dot (`.`)  as a CSS or jQuery selector. If you used `newDivClass` as a jQuery selector without the dot then the selector will try targeting a tag called `newDivClass` ex. `<newDivClass id="doesNotExist" class="thisIsAClass">This is content</newDivClass>` The chances of something like that being on your page is pretty slim. If the selector has no quotes, then it'll look for an plain JavaScript object named `newDivClass`, while this is more plausible, I doubt it. Do you use the developer tools (F12) to see your elements in the DOM?

Comment: yes. I watched the DOM, and console log a lot of things just to catch this weird thing. I knew that we need the (`.`) prefix for css, but I'm not trying to targeting it here. I'm trying to create a div with that class name, so it shouldn't need the (`.`) prefix. It's on the tutorial page for jQuery too. But they try to append a div with an id instead. They don't need the `#` prefix for id element too. http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: We need you to create a [mcve] to reproduce the problem as closely as you are able to with the minimal amount of code. Did you take a look at my demo? That's an [mcve] in the context of an answer, try to make something like my post but as a specific question. I'll be back later.

Comment: Sorry that my example is not clear enough. Because this behavior I have never seen before too, so I don't really know how to explain it. I'll try to figure it out (once again) now. If I can still get it to work, I'll try to give a better example. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: How do you determine `$(_this)` ? is it just like `$(this)`? or `this`?

Comment: @TrangVo are you sure `$(_this)` is actually `$(this)`? Prefixing a variable with an underscore is a naming convention. So while a `var _x` denotes a private variable, it only indicates it as such to a human reader. Code wise it is just a character so while harmless to a variable, I'd say it looks like it could break things if prefixed to a special object like `this`.

Comment: I just solved the problem by changing the class name ( I still have no idea why the other class name doesn't work). I explained it in details in my original question. `_this = this.element` , it's just a private variable to use in the function that I preference back to my public variable.